# How to push in array and use Id as index of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

This is the result I want to achieve

```
    11:{amount:736
    wrk_pay_id:11},

    10:{amount:714.29
    wrk_pay_id:10},

    14:{amount:500
    wrk_pay_id:14},

    13:{amount:857.14
    wrk_pay_id:13},
   
    20:{amount:777
    wrk_pay_id:20}
```

this the result of DeductionArray.. I want to change `0,1,2,3,4` indexes to `11,10,14,13,20`

```
 0:{amount:736
    wrk_pay_id:11},

    1:{amount:714.29
    wrk_pay_id:10},

    2:{amount:500
    wrk_pay_id:14},

    3:{amount:857.14
    wrk_pay_id:13},
   
    4:{amount:777
    wrk_pay_id:20}
```

This how I push it on my DeductionArray.. `this.generated salary` Have `4 object` and the `deduction` is on nested array so that I use `2 foreach` to get the value in `deduction`

```js
const arr = Object.entries(this.generated_salary)
arr.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  Object.entries(value.deduction).forEach(([acc, item]) => {
    this.DeductionArray.push({
      amount: item.amount,
      wrk_pay_id: item.wrk_pay_id
    })
```

This.generated_salay

```
[
  {
    "f_name": "Cy",
    "deduction": {
      "11": {
        "amount": 736,
        "wrk_pay_id": 11
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "f_name": "Hel",
    "deduction": {
      "10": {
        "amount": 714.29,
        "wrk_pay_id": 10
      },
      "14": {
        "amount": 500,
        "wrk_pay_id": 14
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "f_name": "edd",
    "deduction": {
      "13": {
        "amount": 857.14,
        "wrk_pay_id": 13
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "f_name": "JAY",
    "deduction": {
      "20": {
        "amount": 777,
        "wrk_pay_id": 20
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223679/discussion-on-question-by-not-a-pro-how-to-push-in-array-and-use-id-as-index-of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still guessing due to your question formatting but it looks like you really just want to combine the various `deduction` objects into a single object. I don't think an array is a good choice if you're relying on the indexes as keys.

```js
// ignore this line, this is just your existing data minified for the demo
const generated_salary = [{"f_name":"Cy","deduction":{"11":{"amount":736,"wrk_pay_id":11}}},{"f_name":"Hel","deduction":{"10":{"amount":714.29,"wrk_pay_id":10},"14":{"amount":500,"wrk_pay_id":14}}},{"f_name":"edd","deduction":{"13":{"amount":857.14,"wrk_pay_id":13}}},{"f_name":"JAY","deduction":{"20":{"amount":777,"wrk_pay_id":20}}}]

const deductions = generated_salary.reduce((c, { deduction }) => ({
  ...c,
  ...deduction
}), {})

console.info("deductions =", deductions)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This builds a new object by iterating each entry in `generated_salary` and collecting each `deduction` object by merging it into the collection as it finds them.

See also [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Spread Syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

Comment: How can I push or put the result in DeductionArray?

Comment: Like I said, you should not use an array. Instead use a plain object. The code in my answer names this object `deductions`

Comment: can you explain whait is the meaning of `...c` why u use `...`

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals

Comment: can you help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567103/how-to-remove-null-value-in-object-in-vue-js