# How to remove null value in array of objects using reduce?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove null or empty values:

```js
const generated_salary = [{"f_name":"Cy","deduction":{"11":{"amount":736,"wrk_pay_id":11}}},{"f_name":"Hel","deduction":{"10":{"amount":714.29,"wrk_pay_id":10},"14":{"amount":500,"wrk_pay_id":14}}},{"f_name":"edd","deduction":{"13":{"amount":857.14,"wrk_pay_id":13}}},{"f_name":"JAY","deduction":{"":{"amount":"","wrk_pay_id":""}}}]

const deductions = generated_salary.reduce((c, { deduction }) => ({
  ...c,
  ...deduction
}), {})

console.info("deductions =", deductions)
```

My result I want to achieve:

```
info: deductions = {
  "10": {
    "amount": 714.29,
    "wrk_pay_id": 10
  },
  "11": {
    "amount": 736,
    "wrk_pay_id": 11
  },
  "13": {
    "amount": 857.14,
    "wrk_pay_id": 13
  },
  "14": {
    "amount": 500,
    "wrk_pay_id": 14
  }
]
```

Comment: There is no vue.js in that code, this is all vanilla JavaScript (references to vue.js removed).

Comment: but I code this on my vue.js it works the problem is I want to remove null or empty object

Comment: Please add the result you want to achieve for the given input sample.

Comment: It does not matter that you run it on vue.js. For one thing, vue.js itself is also only JavaScript, and for another thing, this particular code sample has *nothing* in it that depends on vue.js, so your question is not related to vue.js.

Comment: @Tomalak Im so sorry I am new in programming

Comment: where is the null object in the input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try this,
I did add an additional loop to remove the null or empty string of key,
you can improve it as needed though

```js
const generated_salary = [{"f_name":"Cy","deduction":{"11":{"amount":736,"wrk_pay_id":11}}},{"f_name":"Hel","deduction":{"10":{"amount":714.29,"wrk_pay_id":10},"14":{"amount":500,"wrk_pay_id":14}}},{"f_name":"edd","deduction":{"13":{"amount":857.14,"wrk_pay_id":13}}},{"f_name":"JAY","deduction":{"":{"amount":"","wrk_pay_id":""}}}]

const deductions = generated_salary.reduce((c, { deduction }) => {
return ({
  ...c,
  ...deduction
})
}, {})

Object.keys(deductions).map((key) => {
  if (key === null || key === '') delete deductions[key]
})

console.info("deductions =", deductions)
```

Comment: This code is similar what I did  few hours ago but didn't work lol.. But this it works well !!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to only add new entries to the result object `c` when the `amount` inside `deduction` is non-empty:

```
const deductions = generated_salary.reduce( (c, {deduction}) => {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(deduction)) {
        if (value.amount) c[key] = value;
    }
    return c;
}, {});
```

---

If you want it fancier:

```
const deductions = generated_salary.reduce( (c, {deduction}) => ({
  ...c,
  ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(deduction).filter(([key, value]) => value.amount))
}), {});
```

...but personally I find this harder to follow than the `for` loop. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
> each element of the array, resulting in **single output value**.

Further info [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

In your case, I would suggest using the filter function as it creates a new array containing all the elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Further info [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Example solution

```
const generated_salary = [
{"f_name":"Cy",
"deduction":{"11":{"amount":736,"wrk_pay_id":11}}},
{
    "f_name":"Hel","deduction":{"10":{"amount":714.29,"wrk_pay_id":10},
    "14":{"amount":500,"wrk_pay_id":14}}},
    {"f_name":"edd","deduction":{"13":{"amount":857.14,"wrk_pay_id":13}}}
    ,{"f_name":"JAY","deduction":{"":{"amount":"","wrk_pay_id":""}}}]

 const deductions = generated_salary.reduce((c, { deduction }) => ({
   ...c,
    ...deduction
   }), {})

Object.keys(deductions).filter((key) => {
(key == null || key == '')
 })
```